# Как я могу добавить анимацию в мой круговой progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

У меня есть круглый `progress bar`, который состоит из двух путей.  На одном из этих путей длина увеличивается по мере поступления данных, в результате чего весь круг становится красным.

SVG HTML

```
<path d="M 50,50 m 0,-47 a 47,47 0 1 1 0,94 a 47,47 0 1 1 0,-94" stroke="#A9B0B7" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="0">
  </path>

  <path id="path2" d="M 50,50 m 0,-47 a 47,47 0 1 1 0,94 a 47,47 0 1 1 0,-94" stroke="#EB483F" stroke-width="6" fill-opacity="0" style="stroke-dasharray: 295.416, 295.416; stroke-dashoffset: 250"></path>
  </svg>
```

CSS (просто делает более гладкой загрузку красного патча )

```
#path2 {
  -webkit-transition-property: stroke-dashoffset; /* Safari */
  transition-property: stroke-dashoffset;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.viewbox {
  width: 50%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5yb5kr9/)

Я хотел бы, чтобы у оставшейся серой части пути была анимация, такая как маленький `div`, проходящий по ней и при этом подцвечивая её. Что-то похожее на это:

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader)

Я считаю, что мне нужно добавить какую-то анимацию `keyframe` и поместить `div` внутри `Path svg`, но я точно не знаю, как это сделать.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I put an animation in the path of my circular progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43144787/7394871) от участника  [@RP12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7459385/rp12).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144787/how-can-i-put-an-animation-in-the-path-of-my-circular-progress-bar

Answer (score 2):

Вот один из способов сделать пульсирующую анимацию  на круговом `progress bar`.

Чтобы импульсный эффект проявлялся внутри растущего `progress bar`, необходимо создание импульсного эффекта в виде собственной анимации, которая затем маскируется (соединяется) с  фактической анимацией `progress arc`.

- Во-первых, давайте начнем с простого красного `progress bar`. Я
  добавил анимацию роста для тестирования.

```css
.viewbox {
  width: 50%;
}

#progress {
  stroke-dasharray: 296 296;
  stroke-dashoffset: 296;
  animation: grow 5s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="viewbox" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <circle id="grey" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
          transform="rotate(-90 50 50)"
          stroke="#A9B0B7" stroke-width="4" fill="none"/>
  
  <circle id="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
          transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" pointer-events="all"
          stroke="#EB483F" stroke-width="6" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

- Затем давайте создадим нашу пульсирующую анимацию, которая имитирует
  пример, [который вы дали в ответе, который был удален.](http://materializecss.com/preloader.html)

```css
.viewbox {
  width: 50%;
}

#pulse {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 0 0 296;
  animation: pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
   33% { stroke-dasharray: 0   0 148 296; }
   66% { stroke-dasharray: 0  50 200 296; }
  100% { stroke-dasharray: 0 296   0 296; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="viewbox" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="#EB483F"/>
  <circle id="pulse" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
          transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" pointer-events="all"
          stroke="white" stroke-width="8" stroke-opacity="0.4" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Это просто полупрозрачный круг (с `dash` анимацией) на красном фоне.

- Предпоследним шагом является преобразование первого примера в форму,
  которая нам нужна для маски. В масках черный цвет прозрачен, а белый
  непрозрачен.

```css
.viewbox {
  width: 50%;
}

#progress {
  stroke-dasharray: 296 296;
  stroke-dashoffset: 296;
  animation: grow 5s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="viewbox" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="black"/>
  
  <circle id="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
          transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" pointer-events="all"
          stroke="white" stroke-width="6" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

- Последний шаг - объединить предыдущие два шага. Мы превращаем
  предыдущий шаг в правильную маску `<mask>` и используем её для
  маскирования импульсной анимации.

```css
.viewbox {
  width: 50%;
}

#progress {
  stroke-dasharray: 296 296;
  stroke-dashoffset: 296;
  animation: grow 5s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}

#pulse {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 0 0 296;
  animation: pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
   33% { stroke-dasharray: 0   0 148 296; }
   66% { stroke-dasharray: 0  50 200 296; }
  100% { stroke-dasharray: 0 296   0 296; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="viewbox" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <defs>
    <mask id="progress-as-mask" >
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="black"/>
      <circle id="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
              transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" pointer-events="all"
              stroke="white" stroke-width="6" fill="none"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <circle id="grey" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
          transform="rotate(-90 50 50)"
          stroke="#A9B0B7" stroke-width="4" fill="none"/>

  <g mask="url(#progress-as-mask)">
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="#EB483F"/>
    <circle id="pulse" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
            transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" pointer-events="all"
            stroke="white" stroke-width="8" stroke-opacity="0.4" fill="none"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [How can I put an animation in the path of my circular progress bar? @Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43167953/7394871)